# How can I put a search box for one page in another page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search, plugins, elementor

I have two pages on my wordpress site, one displays the database of various medicines using ninja tables plugin and on other page I want to display a functioning search bar that will search in the database. I am working with Elementor, is there any way by which this can be done, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Ninja tables by default provides a powerful search bar. Enable it in the `Table Design -> Enable the visitor to filter or search the table`.

[image]

If you want to display just the database on a page you can hide the search bar using CSS ( Since due the setting above, search bar will appear on all pages with the search) with something like this:

```
.ninja_table_wrapper .footable-filtering-search {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Refer [the doc](https://wpmanageninja.com/docs/ninja-tables/designing-tables/search-filter-functionality/) for more info

Comment: I want to the search bar on a different page and database on a different one, how can this be done? The doc you shared just tells how to add or remove the search bar on the same page

Comment: I have mentioned in the answer, where you don't want the search bar, use the css and hide it. There maybe a better way to use a action hook on the specific page in `functions.php`. But the css method should also work.